# Initialise a Jquery Widget on Demand with Jquery

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery

I have loaded my **layered navigation** over **ajax** to speed up my site load. The layered navigation also uses ajax and it's **jQuery** is normally initialised via **RequireJS** i believe with the below requireJS config:

```
var config = {
"map": {
    "*": {
        "productListToolbarForm": "CzoneTech_AjaxifiedCatalog/js/product/list/toolbar"
    }
  }
};
```

This i think overrides the default functionality of Magento's **productListToolbarForm** widget which Magento initialises on category pages.

As the markup isn't there on page load i need to initialise this in the success function of my ajax call for the layered nav so the markup is present when this jQuery runs.

The **Widget** looks like below:

```
$.widget('mage.productListToolbarForm', $.mage.productListToolbarForm, {
    ...
}
```

I have tried:

```
$('#layered-filter-block').productListToolbarForm();
```

This seems to work when i use chrome however not when i use safari or internet explorer. How can i properly initialise this JS when my ajax call completes?